# Accessing AngularJS variable in view?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

Consider basic AngularJS application with just one controller. Inside the controller I have set-up "myVariable" to hold a value "Test".

I am given an inline JavaScript code in the view and I need to call a function **samplefunction** which takes a parameter using **myVariable**.

```
/* Controllers */

angular.module('myApp.controllers', [])
    .controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {

        $scope.myVariable = "Test";

    });
```

In the view, in the html file, this is what I need to do:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var param1 = {{myVariable}};   /* <-- how to make this work?  */
    samplefunction( param1 );   

</script>
```

It doesn't work though. I just need to assign myVariable value to the **param1**. I also tried something like:

```
...
var param1 = angular.element(document.getElementById("mainBody")).scope().myVariable
...
```

But this didn't work either. 
Please, note that I cannot touch the given JS code that I am calling in the view.

Anyone knows how to solve this simple issue?

Comment: `angular.element(document.getElementById("mainBody")).scope().myVariable` should work - what is the output

Answer (score 1):

From my POV what you are doing shouldn't be done. The closest correct approach should be:

Setting your **view** with a value in the way angular was meant to be used:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="myVariable" id="myVar" />
```

and iff you want to you get your var value get it from the **view** like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
    var param1 = document.getElementById("myVal").value;
    samplefunction( param1 );   
</script>
```

**[Online Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/H6w9e/)**

Answer (score 0):

Pass the var to $window to expose it to your JS.

`$window.myVariable = $scope.myVariable;`

Comment: I was trying to do that, but it didn't work. 
    ...
    samplefunction( $window.myVariable )

Comment: Is that function in your vanilla JS? Or in Angular?

Answer (score 0):

What about binding the scope variable to a data-something attribute on an element in your view,  and then pull it using Jquery in your external script tag?

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
    var param1 = $("#someId").data("myValue");
    samplefunction( param1 );   
</script>
```